# How to select only top and bot row from a table

Tags: sql

I am trying to select top and bottom row from a table as below but got error messages:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'
```

What is the correct way to use 'UNION'?

```
Use DATABASE
Go
declare @Volume VARCHAR(512)
set @Volume = '599722'


SELECT    
TOP (1)
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive as FirstArchive,  
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].cr_time,
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].group_name,
[VOLUME].vol_name,
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].display_name
FROM            
ARCHIVE_HEADER INNER JOIN VOLUME
ON ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
WHERE        
VOLUME.vol_name = @Volume
ORDER BY
ARCHIVE_HEADER.archive ASC

UNION

SELECT    
TOP (1)
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive as FirstArchive,  
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].cr_time,
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].group_name,
[VOLUME].vol_name,
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].display_name
FROM            
ARCHIVE_HEADER INNER JOIN VOLUME
ON ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
WHERE        
VOLUME.vol_name = @Volume
ORDER BY
ARCHIVE_HEADER.archive DESC
```

From performance perspective, this has to query the same table twice for the result, is there a better logic can only query once for the same result?

Comment: I actually would have thought that would work but I think you can only have one ORDER BY... Your looping question probably deserves its own post :)

Comment: removed the last question, added a related question

Comment: Presuming SQL Server, the optimizer is likely to do its job well enough to not worry about performance differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think this would be simpler using a single query:

```
SELECT FirstArchive, cr_time, group_name, vol_name, display_name
FROM (SELECT ah.archive as FirstArchive, ah.cr_time, ah.group_name,
             v.vol_name, ah.display_name,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.vol_name ORDER BY ah.archive ASC) as seqnum_asc,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.vol_name ORDER BY ah.archive DESC) as seqnum_desc
      FROM ARCHIVE_HEADER ah INNER JOIN
           VOLUME v
           ON ah.volume_key = v.volume_key
      WHERE v.vol_name = @Volume
     ) ah
WHERE 1 IN (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)
ORDER BY ah.archive ASC;
```

There is no need to `UNION ALL` two subqueries.

Note:  This has one difference from your query.  If there is only one row for the `volume`, then this returns one row rather than two.  This seems like an improvement.

Comment: I will accept this one as the best answer, the subquery one is easy to understand tho...

Answer (score 2):

use subquery

```
    select * from (
SELECT    
    TOP (1)
    [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive as FirstArchive,  
    [ARCHIVE_HEADER].cr_time,
    [ARCHIVE_HEADER].group_name,
    [VOLUME].vol_name,
    [ARCHIVE_HEADER].display_name
    FROM            
    ARCHIVE_HEADER INNER JOIN VOLUME
    ON ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
    WHERE        
    VOLUME.vol_name = @Volume
    ORDER BY
    ARCHIVE_HEADER.archive ASC
) a        
    UNION
 select * from (        
    SELECT    
    TOP (1)
    [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive as FirstArchive,  
    [ARCHIVE_HEADER].cr_time,
    [ARCHIVE_HEADER].group_name,
    [VOLUME].vol_name,
    [ARCHIVE_HEADER].display_name
    FROM            
    ARCHIVE_HEADER INNER JOIN VOLUME
    ON ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
    WHERE        
    VOLUME.vol_name = @Volume
    ORDER BY
    ARCHIVE_HEADER.archive DESC
) b
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question...

You could use a temp table. Something like:

```
declare @Volume VARCHAR(512)
set @Volume = '599722'


SELECT    
TOP (1)
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive as FirstArchive,  
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].cr_time,
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].group_name,
[VOLUME].vol_name,
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].display_name
INTO #t --this step creates the temp table
FROM            
ARCHIVE_HEADER INNER JOIN VOLUME
ON ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
WHERE        
VOLUME.vol_name = @Volume
ORDER BY
ARCHIVE_HEADER.archive ASC

INSERT INTO #t
SELECT    
TOP (1)
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive as FirstArchive,  
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].cr_time,
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].group_name,
[VOLUME].vol_name,
[ARCHIVE_HEADER].display_name
FROM            
ARCHIVE_HEADER INNER JOIN VOLUME
ON ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
WHERE        
VOLUME.vol_name = @Volume
ORDER BY
ARCHIVE_HEADER.archive DESC

--now both records should be in #t
SELECT *
FROM #t
```

Comment: Thank you, i will give it a try as well.

Comment: Don't forget to drop the temp table.  (Which is why I recommend using a table variable instead.)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to union, you could use min and max in a subquery and then inner join.
**untested**

```
select [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive,  
   [ARCHIVE_HEADER].cr_time,
   [ARCHIVE_HEADER].group_name,
   [VOLUME].vol_name,
   [ARCHIVE_HEADER].display_name
from ARCHIVE_HEADER
inner join (
   select min(archive) FirstArchive, max(archive) LastArchive
   from ARCHIVE_HEADER
   inner join VOLUME on ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
   where VOLUME.vol_name = @Volume
) MinMax_Archive
   on [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive = FirstArchive
   or [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive = LastArchive
inner join VOLUME on ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
where VOLUME.vol_name = @Volume
order by [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive
```

For multiple volumes, the following should list ALL volumes:
**even more untested**

```
select [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive,  
   [ARCHIVE_HEADER].cr_time,
   [ARCHIVE_HEADER].group_name,
   [VOLUME].vol_name,
   [ARCHIVE_HEADER].display_name
from ARCHIVE_HEADER
inner join VOLUME on ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
inner join (
   select volume_key min(archive) FirstArchive, max(archive) LastArchive
   from ARCHIVE_HEADER
   group by volume_key
) MinMax_Archive
   on ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = MinMax_Archive.volume_key
   and ( [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive = FirstArchive
         or [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive = LastArchive)
order by vol_name, [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive
```

To limit it to some volumes, you can list them directly using IN:

```
select [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive,  
   [ARCHIVE_HEADER].cr_time,
   [ARCHIVE_HEADER].group_name,
   [VOLUME].vol_name,
   [ARCHIVE_HEADER].display_name
from ARCHIVE_HEADER
inner join VOLUME on ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = VOLUME.volume_key
inner join (
   select volume_key min(archive) FirstArchive, max(archive) LastArchive
   from ARCHIVE_HEADER
   group by volume_key
) MinMax_Archive
   on ARCHIVE_HEADER.volume_key = MinMax_Archive.volume_key
   and vol_name in ('599722', '458933', '342902')
   and ( [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive = FirstArchive
         or [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive = LastArchive)
order by vol_name, [ARCHIVE_HEADER].archive
```

If you want to use a variable for the multiple volumes, then it gets a little tricky.  You'll want to create a table variable (or temp table) of the vol_name's that you want and then inner join that table to the rest.

Comment: `in ('599722', '458933', '342902')` , I have over 7k volumes, i think better loop them through instead of list them in my sql script. I will try your code out

Comment: Where are you getting the list of 7k volumes from?

Comment: that list is from volume table, it contains all the tapes we have in the library.

Comment: Are you saying you want all of the volumes?  That's the 2nd one above.  If not, I was asking how you choose which 7000 of the however-many volumes you you have that you want to report on.